# Query Regarding DynamoDB Pricing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an use case wherein, I need to read data from DynamoDB each 30 seconds.
And the number of items the client will be reading will always be 200, now it is known that each item is less than 4KB, so this batch read will use 200 Read Capacity Units. But the 200 Read Capacity Units will be used in a 30 seconds interval, so how much would I be paying for this per hour ?
Will it be same as 200*(0.00725/10) USD per hour or something else ?

Comment: It might help to explain what it is you're trying to do and also how you're reading your items (get vs scan vs query)

Comment: I am doing batch get item, but will that matter ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You will be paying for the hour.
The price of dynamodb is based on provisioned throughput and size of the data.

The provisioned throughput is preconfigured and charged irrespective of whether you consume the available throughput or not.

You have the option of controlling the throughput configurations through APIs, but that also has limits on how many times you can do it in a day.

Since you will querying every 30 seconds, increasing & decreasing throughput may not be option, since the increase and decrease is not instantaneous.